# How to have gifs wait for each other?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have 2 gifs that will keep repeating in my powerpoint slide. Gif A has 40 frames while the gif B has only 20. How do I get gif B to wait till A is finished before restarting its animation ?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to achieve the effect that you are looking for:

1. Add an extra 20 copies of the final frame of the shorter animation to the end of that GIF so that both GIFs have the same number of frames.
2. Change the timing of the last frame in the shorter animation so that it is 21 times the length of all the other frames. How you do that will depend on what software you are using to create and edit the GIFs.